# Assign a variable to keep it memorized for a chess game

Tags: python, chess

```
        SauvegardePlateau = plateau         
        print(SauvegardePlateau)
        deplacement(VP,X1,Y1,X2,Y2) #changes the value in the first "plateau"
        dessinpieces()
        print(SauvegardePlateau)
        Turn=0

        if SauvegardePlateau != plateau:
            if Joueur==1:
                Joueur=2
            else:
                Joueur=1
```

at the first "print(SauvegardePlateau)" it gives me the "plateau" as it should do but on the second print it gives me the one that has been changed when i only changed "plateau" and didn't change "SauvegardePlateau"

the aim is to be able to cancel a move, so I need to save the plateau in a variable (SauvegardePlateau) before my main plateau changes but wiredly they both change which means that my "if SauvegardePlateau != plateau" never works

I don't understand why it's doing that, if you could please help me ? Thanks ! (sorry for english errors i'm french)

Comment: is `plateau` a list ?

Comment: Just an advice Thomas, if you are starting in python, please find out best practices regarding the way code is written, Python makes use of snake_case and not CamelCase as @Arnaud Prest clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit your question to sort things out, hence why I'm making this answer.
First, some translation, so that others have an easier time reading the code:

- "Plateau" = "Board"
- "SauvegardePlateau" = "Save Board" (although "Backup Board" is more appropriate)
- "deplacement" = "move"
- "dessinpieces" = "draw (chess) pieces"

Now that this is out of the way, let's address your actual problem:

First, you *should* stick to proper style guidelines, as defined in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This will greatly improve the readability of your code.

On the technical part, what you are trying to do is:

- Backup the board
- Change the board's state by moving a piece
- Checking backup you made earlier

In python, if you do the following:

```
>>> board = ["Begin"]
>>> backup = board
>>> board.append("Change!")
>>> backup
['Begin', 'Change!']
```

You can clearly highlight the issue. `backup` is **not** a copy of `board`, but a *link* to it.
To obtain a proper "copy" of your list, and judging from the code sample you've provided, it looks like:

```
sauvegarde_plateau = list(plateau)
```

Will suit your needs.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! Helped me a lot, thanks for the time you put in to explain me this and yes sorry I should've translated it ! (Though it's for my BAC (A levels equivalent) so I need it all in french).
Anyway thank you for your detailed answer.